# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dissociate()

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I am dissociate  all the stoppages from a route but I am getting this error. I have defined hasMany relation in Route model and belongs to in stoppage model.

```
$routeObject = \App\Models\Routes::with('hasManyStoppages')
    ->where('id', '=', $request->id)
    ->first();
if (!empty($routeObject->hasManyStoppages)) {
     $routeObject->hasManyStoppages()->dissociate();
     $routeObject->save();
}
```

Comment: `dissociate()` is only used with a **belongsTo** relationship, I'm guessing you have a many-to-many relationship, so you should use `detach()` to remove all the related models.

Comment: one route can have many stoppages, it's a one to many relation and I have also defined belongs to relation in stoppage model

Comment: Could you post the part of code that defines the relation hasManyStoppages?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, So I guess I learnt something new ( maybe they changed it in 5.6), but in a one-to-many relationship you can't use detach from the parent object anymore. Only delete works 
(but this deletes the child entry)